# Can somebody please explain this continuation in scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, continuations

I am learning continuations but I can't wrap my head around this code. Why does it go into infinite loop?

```
(let ((cont #f))
  (call/cc (lambda (k)
             (set! cont k)))
  (cont #f))
```

Comment: I am taking it but we have not reached there. : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line by line:

- we define local variable `cont`
- we call with current continuation some lambda function, that is, we are passing the current continuation to the lambda function as an argument. Current continuation is a function of 1 argument, this argument is then used as a "return value" of `call/cc` (and here is eventually ignored).
- So `k` here signifies everything, that will happen after, in our case something close in sense to `(lambda (call/cc-retval) (let () call/cc-retval (cont #f)))`. We set `cont` value to this continuation. `call/cc` returns.
- Since `cont` is now a function which represented the continuation, and it's argument is the "return value of call/cc", we just call that function, the argument gets ignored, and we need to call the `(cont #f)` again.

Thus, what we get eventually is infinite loop.

Comment: So in the three uses of cont in the example we have it: (1) being defined as a boolean value #f, (2) being set to a continuation value k, (3) being invoked as a function with a boolean argument #f?

Comment: @Chris. Yup.  But the #f is just a dummy value. We could have null or anything because at both times it is ignored.